# FileZilla: My FileZilla does not have two panel layout and says "Warning: FTP over TLS is not enabled users cannot securely login"

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I am brand new to using an FTP server. I just downloaded FileZilla and did nothing different, just kept hitting continue through the insallation and then opened it with the server 127.0.0.1 and the default port.

Now I get this:

[image]

Also when I see other people putting their files on the server they have a different looking application than I do. It is split and has two different sides in which they load the files to the server. I do not see how they got to that. I watch a beginners tutorial, but it did not really explain how to get to that part.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed FileZilla server.

While you probably wanted FileZilla client.

Comment: That would make since ^^ . Thank you so much!